# EJB - error on dependency injection of Entity Manager

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

I get this error:

```
... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManagerFactory.
```

What I want to do is create a entity class User and a session Bean to access the User..

I get the error when I'm executing:

```
User result = null;
String q = "SELECT user FROM " + User.class.getName() + " user WHERE user.username LIKE :username";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(q).setParameter("username", username);
List<User> users = query.getResultList();
if (users.size() > 0) {
    result = users.get(0);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="DS3-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>db_ds_hw3</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

EDIT 1:

injection code:

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "DS3-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: Add the portion of code where you're injecting EntityManager.

Comment: It seems fine. Can you try to ping (through Glassfish) your JDBC connection pool, `db_ds_hw3`.

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably running into a [GlassFish bug in redeployment](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17295) that has been fixed in version 4.0 (not out yet).

For the time being, as explained in the above link, the workaround is to undeploy - redeploy the application.

---

**Related**:

[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManagerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947293/java-lang-illegalstateexception-attempting-to-execute-an-operation-on-a-closed)

Comment: I am using GlassFish yes. I tried to undeploy and redeploy and I get the same issue.

Comment: Probably this happens because when the EMF is closed, it's too late, and you must restart GlassFish. The workaround works when the EMF is still alive.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with this bug too, reload **domain** helped me. In console enter:

```
asadmin restart-domain
```